# How to specify none-existing Spring Dispatcher config xml files in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In the web.xml I like to specify multiple Spring DispatcherServlet config xml files, such that I can add additional beans in test/demo/etc.. environments.

However, how can I specify that Spring has to ignore xml files that don't exists?
Currently I receive an exception when Spring can't find the config file, for example: "demo/front.xml" (it works when the file is present).

My web.xml snippet:
    
      bv-web
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          
            contextConfigLocation
            classpath:front.xml,classpath:${app.env}/front.xml

Alternative:
As an alternative I tried to add extra beans through the root applicationContext.xml (using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) which work as long as it concerns old-fashion Spring controllers that extend "AbstractController". 
However, when using the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations, the controllers are created and added to "a" DispatcherServlet, but aren't  used by the DispatcherServlet. It's like I have multiple DispatcherServlets :(.... I think because they live in different Spring Application contexts (strange however that it works with the old-fashion controller mechanism).

Comment: spring will only look up config files you tell it to ...

Comment: You need to use Spring Profiles.

Comment: @stefoan: that might be an idea, so basically you are saying to mix test and production beans in one xml file and split them up through bean profiles... Not that bad, but might get a bit messy... For the sake of security (else I get all these security boys asking questions) I like test code not to be present in production environment.